# How show a Form of a dll file from console application?

Tags: delphi

I have a dll that contains several Forms.

I have a reference to main function in Console Aplication that loads this dll.

Then, my trouble is that when executes the function of dll, the Form don't appears and execution of dll file and load.exe (Console Application that calls this dll) both are finalizeds respectivally.

So, how solve this trouble?

Here is my code:

**Dll (main part)**

```
library DLL;

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  Connect,
  Classes;

{$R *.res}

procedure ShowDllForm;stdcall;
begin
  Form1 :=TForm1.Create(nil);
  Form1.Show;
end;

exports
 ShowDllForm;

begin
end.
```

**Console Application (load.exe) (calling this dll file)**

```
var
  Msg: TMsg;

  procedure ShowDllForm;stdcall;
    external 'DLL.dll' name 'ShowDllForm';

begin
 CoInitialize(nil);

  ShowDllForm;

while integer(GetMessage(Msg, 0, 0, 0)) = 0 do begin
    TranslateMessage(Msg);
    DispatchMessage(Msg);
  end;

 CoUninitialize;
end.
```

And also, if possible, I want know how execute a main Form in dll file in hidden mode.

Comment: Console applications don't receive messages, because they don't have a window handle. Your entire message loop is a waste of space, because it will never execute.

Comment: @Ken Console apps can have message queues. This one does. It has a window, created in the DLL. You don't need to have a window in order to have a queue. Message queues are owned by threads. See PostThreadMessage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your message loop terminates immediately. A value of 0 is returned when `WM_QUIT` is processed. So the loop will never be entered.  The meaning of the return value is stated clearly in the documentation.

The message loop should be:

```
while GetMessage(Msg, 0, 0, 0) do begin
  TranslateMessage(Msg);
  DispatchMessage(Msg);
end;
```

A non-zero value returned by `GetMessage` means that there is a message to be processed and that `WM_QUIT` has not been processed.

You'll also need to arrange for the DLL to post a quit message when the form closes if you want the process to terminate.

Even so, this may have problems. The VCL expects messages to be pumped by VCL code. There will likely be odd glitches. If it were me I'd place the message loop in the DLL code. In fact, I suggest calling `ShowModal` there and removing the message loop from the host.

```
procedure ShowDllForm; stdcall;
begin
  Form1 := TForm1.Create(nil);
  try
    Form1.ShowModal;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(Form1);
  end;
end;
```

And the host can just call the function and have no need for a message loop. Because `ShowModal` runs a modal message loop.

Comment: OK, I followed all suggestions, but `Form1` still continue closing when execute console application.

Comment: Remember that I don't know what you actually did. Likely you made another mistake.

Comment: Solved. Now you could say me, how I can show this `Form1` in hidden mode please?

Comment: I don't understand the question